how to configure and use dumb-jump
I have following in my init.el file:
(use-package dumb-jump
  :straight t
  :init
)


(add-hook 'xref-backend-functions #'dumb-jump-xref-activate)
(setq xref-show-definitions-function #'xref-show-definitions-completing-read)
;;;(setq xref-backend-functions (remq 'etags--xref-backend xref-backend-functions))
;;(add-to-list 'xref-backend-functions #'dumb-jump-xref-activate)
;;(add-hook 'xref-backend-functions #'dumb-jump-xref-activate)
(setq dumb-jump-default-project "~/Development")

On M-., it asks for find-definitions-for:, but no matter what i ask for I get no definition found.
I am on openBSD with emacs version 29.4. I assume xref is installed.

I assume xref is installed: you can find out if that is the case with M-: (featurep 'xref) - if that returns t, xref is installed. You can use this method with just about any package to find out if it is installed.

that evaluates to t. xref is installed.
